# How do I display one image over the other using CImg.h library?

Tags: c++, image, overlay, x11, cimg

I am trying to display one image over the other but in the same window. I have seen posts doing side by side but I already know how to do that. Here is what I have so far:

```
string firstFile = "";
string secondFile = "";
cout << "Enter the filenames corresponding to the Image and the Logo (in that order): " << endl;
cin >> firstFile;
cin >> secondFile;

const char* filename = firstFile.c_str(); 
CImg<unsigned char> img1(filename); 

const char* filename2 = secondFile.c_str(); 
CImg<unsigned char> img2(filename2); 

int w = img1.width(); 
int h = img1.height(); 
int channels = img1.spectrum(); 

cout << "Successfully loaded image " << firstFile << " of size " << w << " x " << h << " x " << channels << endl;

int w2 = img2.width();
int h2 = img2.height();
channels = img2.spectrum();
cout << "Successfully loaded image " << secondFile << " of size " << w2 << " x " << h2 << " x " << channels << endl;

cout << "Enter the position in (x, y) coordinates where this logo must be placed." << endl << "x must be between 0 and 239 and y must be between 0 and 191." << endl;
int x1, y1;
cin >> x1;
cin >> y1;

char title[100];
sprintf(title, "%s (%d x %d x %d)", filename, w, h, channels);


CImgDisplay disp(img1, title, 0); 
img1.display(disp, false);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
   // Draw img2 on top of img1 at (x1,y1)
   img1.draw_image(x1,y1,img2);
```

Comment: Thank you! Just to note for others that may have the problem I had, I had to put this statement before the img1 was displayed.